# Div won't refresh with Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use Ajax.ActionLink to refresh a list of items on my page.  I can get basic Ajax updates working in a test page without an issue, but in this particular case I'm not able to get it to work.

My Index Controller and View are fairly simple (see below).  The Index View renders the List action, which is where my items are listed and my AjaxLinks are.  The AjaxLinks call an "UpdateStatus" action which changes the status of the item.  After that happens the List should no longer show that item so I return the List action.

However, while the code all executes properly with no errors, the page does nt update or refresh.

Can anyone see my problem?

```
    Public Function Index(Optional ByVal status As String = "Pending") As ActionResult

        ViewBag.Status = status
        Return View()

    End Function

    Public Function List(Optional ByVal status As String = "Pending") As ActionResult

       'Code to populate the model with the filtered list is here'

        Return View(plvm)
    End Function

    Public Function UpdateStatus(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal status As String, ByVal actionStatus As String)
        'Code to update the status is here'

        db.SaveChanges()

        Return List(status)
    End Function
```

Index.vbhtml:

```
    @Code
        ViewData("Title") = "Proposals"
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
    End Code

    @* Some additional render code is here *@

    <div id="dashboardDetails">   
        @Code        
            Html.RenderAction("List", "Proposals", New With {.status = ViewBag.Status})
        End Code
    </div>
```

List.vbhtml:

```
@ModelType CharityMVC.ProposalListViewModel

@Code    
    Layout = ""
End Code
@* Some addtional render code is here (table tags, etc...)  *@
<tbody>
        @For Each item As CharityMVC.Program In Model.Programs
            @:<tr id="prop @item.Id">
                @:<td>@item.Proposal.Organization.Name</td>
                @:<td>@item.Name</td>
                @:<td><div class="buttons">     
                        @Ajax.ActionLink("ajax link", "UpdateStatus", New With {.id = item.Id, .actionStatus = "Tabled", .status = ViewContext.RouteData.Values("status")}, New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "dashboardDetails"})                                        
                @:</div></td>
            @:</tr>

        Next
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: As far as I can see from the code posted, the ActionLink updates the status, which does not appear in the table in List.vbhtml.  From what you posted, the AJAX link can do its work and send back the HTML for the table, but you won't see any change to the table.  Have you tested with "status" as a cell?

Comment: The table is actually filtered by that status, that filter gets applied in the List() method. That is why I was expecting to see the table updated because the item's status becomes 'tabled' instead of 'pending' in the UpdateStatus() method. When I click the ajax link it doesn't even lose focus which tells me the div is not being updated...

Comment: It appears to have something to do with the way I'm "nesting" the return (returning the list function). When I duplicate the list code in my UpdateStatus method and call: Return View("List",plvm) it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess/answer so far:

It appears to have something to do with the way I'm "nesting" the return (returning the list function).

If I duplicate the List() method call inside my UpdateStatus and use the following line:

```
Return View("List",plvm)
```

It works, sort of.

Sometimes it doesn't return any data, just blanks out the entire list and leaves it there and I have to reload the entire page.  Is that a bug in the ajax implementation?